# What is the correct form of this derivative

Tags: linear-algebra

I am seeing in a book that the derivative with respect to $x$ of $\nu^T(Ax-b) = \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\nu^T(Ax-b) = A^T\nu$

I am wondering if the book is wrong, or if the answer should be $\nu^TA$ instead of $A^T\nu$

The dimensions are different in both cases.

If $A$ is $m \times n$, $x = n\times 1$, $\nu=m\times 1$

Then $\nu^TA = ( 1 \times m )( m \times n ) = 1 \times n$

and, $A^T\nu = ( n \times m )( m \times 1 ) = n\times 1$

But for original function, $\nu(Ax-b)$, it is $(1\times m)[(m \times n)(n \times1) - (m \times 1)] = (1 \times 1)$

So... Which derivative answer is correct, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}\nu^T(Ax-b)=\frac{\partial (\sum_k v_ka_{ki}x_i) }{\partial x_i}=\sum_kv_ka_{ki}$$

then

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\nu^T(Ax-b) =\begin{bmatrix}\sum_kv_ka_{k1}\\\sum_kv_ka_{k2}\\\ldots \\\sum_kv_ka_{kn} \end{bmatrix}=A^T\nu$$

Note that $(v^TA)=A^Tv$ therefore both contains essentially the same information, the form to use depends essentially upon the convention we are adopting in order to express the result by column or row vector.